# Is it possible to use an int variable to set the size of another variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables

I'm pretty new to SQL so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.
All I'm tyring to is use an integer variable to set the size of a nvarchar variable.

```
DECLARE @asdf int
SET @asdf = 255
DECLARE @qwer nvarchar(@asdf)
```

Am I missing something or is that just not possible? I can't really find anything about this specific case online so that's why I am asking here.

Comment: This isn't really possible.

Comment: There's always dynamic SQL, but I suspect it's probably not a really good use case for it. When in doubt, you can use `nvarchar(4000)` since it will take only as much length as it needs.

Comment: Are you really trying to implement an array of some sort?

Comment: It would probably be better to ask a question about the *problem* for which you think this is (part of) a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to worried for performance. The `NVARCHAR(x)` will consume only the space it needs to hold the value.

You can use dynamic T-SQL statement like this (but there is no point):

```
DECLARE @asdf int
SET @asdf = 5

DECLARE @DynamicTSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
DECLARE @qwer nvarchar('+CAST(@asdf AS VARCHAR(12))+')
SET @qwer = ''1234567890'';
SELECT @qwer
';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQL
```

You can store the value in [sql_variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) column. It basically allows to store different types in one column. Once stored, you can cast them to the target type and perform appropriate operations depending it.